# Why does my button view id change at runtime?

Tags: android, kotlin

I'm trying to write a simple Android application in Kotlin that changes the colors of different Views.

I have the following code to initialize views and click listeners (private lateinit declarations earlier of course):

```
private fun setListeners()
{
    boxOneText = findViewById(R.id.box_one_text)
    boxTwoText = findViewById(R.id.box_two_text)
    boxThreeText = findViewById(R.id.box_three_text)
    boxFourText = findViewById(R.id.box_four_text)
    boxFiveText = findViewById(R.id.box_five_text)

    btnRed = findViewById(R.id.button_red)
    btnYellow = findViewById(R.id.button_yellow)
    btnBlue = findViewById(R.id.button_blue)

    val rootLayout = findViewById<View>(R.id.constraint_layout)

    // Set click listener for all text views
    val views = listOf<View>(boxOneText, boxTwoText, boxThreeText, boxFourText, boxFiveText, rootLayout)
    views.map { view -> view.setOnClickListener { makeColored(it) } }

    // Set click listener for all buttons
    val buttons = listOf(btnRed, btnYellow, btnBlue)
    buttons.map { button -> button.setOnClickListener { makeSpecificColor(it, views) } }
}
```

The code to set the colors of individual TextViews looks like this, and works (disregard the lockdown_earth entry for box_two, I was playing around with stuff):

```
private fun makeColored(view: View)
{
    when(view.id)
    {
        R.id.box_one_text -> view.setBackgroundColor(Color.DKGRAY)
        R.id.box_two_text -> view.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.lockdown_earth)
        R.id.box_three_text -> view.setBackgroundColor(Color.BLUE)
        R.id.box_four_text -> view.setBackgroundColor(Color.MAGENTA)
        R.id.box_five_text -> view.setBackgroundColor(Color.BLUE)
        else -> view.setBackgroundColor(Color.LTGRAY)
    }
}
```

However, the following code to change the color of **all** TextViews (including the rootLayout) does **not work**:

```
// In this context, view is a Button
private fun makeSpecificColor(view: View, views: List<View>)
{
    // TODO For some reason the id doesn't match??
    val color = when(view.id)
    {
        R.id.button_yellow -> R.color.my_yellow
        R.id.button_red -> R.color.my_red
        R.id.button_blue -> R.color.my_blue
        else -> R.color.colorPrimary
    }

    views.map { it.setBackgroundColor(color) }
}
```

As alluded to by my TODO, for some reason the view id is **NOT** what it was before the clickListener was triggered, and the 'else' is always entered. I have run this in debug mode and the passed ID doesn't match any of the Views I have in the entire app. Is a new ID being assigned somehow? If so, why do the TextViews work with their listener?

Is it due to my usage of map on the buttons list? I have been kinda blindly using that as a replacement for a for loop.

Comment: @Matte  Corby, I delete the answer, if you don't know, I think you do not use it.

Comment: The only issue I found in the given code is the color value/resource mix-up that Zbarcea Christian mentioned in their (now-deleted) answer. I ran a quick debug to check the ID discrepancy, and indeed they do not match up properly. However, the `view.id` was the correct one, with the `R.id`s showing invalid values in the debugger. I've seen this before, but I never have tracked down why those `R` values aren't correct there. Stepping through the code followed the expected branch, though, and the color was set correctly, after fixing the `setBackgroundColor()` argument.

Comment: As an aside, it's probably more appropriate to use `forEach()` instead of `map()`, unless you plan on doing something with the returns, at some point.

Comment: So this is just some weird error that no one knows the answer to? I'm glad you were at least able to duplicate the issue. @MikeM.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean. As I mentioned, the only thing wrong with your code is the color value/resource mix-up; i.e., `it.setBackgroundColor(color)` should be something like `it.setBackgroundColor(getColor(color))`. The debugger issue isn't really related, other than it's confusing the issue, currently.

Comment: @MikeM. Sorry, upon rereading your comment I see that the code actually worked for you. For me, I always get the 'else' in `makeSpecificColor()` when I use any of the red, yellow, or green buttons. You're saying that for you, you actually get the other colors? And it was all because I didn't use `getColor(color)`?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

It turned out the issue was that I was using the wrong method to set the background color. Instead of using `setBackgroundColor()` I needed to use `setBackgroundResource()`.

It's unfortunate the debugger doesn't resolve resource IDs correctly because it sent me down a rabbit hole trying to fix the wrong problem.